# Smart way for resetting class attributes after deleting data

Tags: python

I have a class that does some data cleaning.

```
class Data:
  def __init__(data):
    self.data = data
    self.T = data.shape[0]
    self.n = data.shape[1]
    self.N = self.T * self.n
    ...

  def clean_data():
    # does something which removes observations
    return clean_data
```

This is a stylized example, my class has much more attributes and has three datasets that depend on each other for cleaning (e.g. I would clean dataset1 based on whether something happened in dataset2 etc) and also more attributes. In my current design, `clean_data()` method simply returns a new dataset which I may or may not replace `self.data` if I desire. However, this is not optimal since if I remove observations or add observations I need to change every attribute of the init.

Any advice? Can this be somehow done with getters and setter?

Comment: Can you just have some data 'presets', then call `__init__(preset1)` from `clean_data()` ?

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Do you want `clean_data` to 'reset' the values in the class instance, or just return the original data (but leave the updated attributes alone) ?

Comment: Ideally, I would have `clean_data` not returning, but actually resetting `self.data = clean_data` and then subsequently updating all the attributes. The essence of `clean_data` is that, it does what it does and produces a filter, whereby `clean_data = data[filter]`, so this filter needs to be applied to other attributes as well. For example, self.a = self.a[filter] and then self.b = len(self.a).